# How to delete whitespace backward in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I would like to use Xcode editor instead of others for swift typing but I am missing basic functionality of deleting whitespace backward.

Normally in the world of code editors, you just press option + backspace or something similar and thats it, it deletes whitespace just until next character starts, eating new line in the way as everyone needs.

But xCode is doing some wired unusable staff and is deleting not just whitespace and new line, but also part of text on previous line, until it considers some character start of word, basically making it unusable.

I don't need to know how to use "Delete subword backward" !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this can be done in xcode. Right now (xcode15.0.1) the default function for `Option+Backspace` is "Delete Word Backward" which actually means delete the last word behind the cursor including any special characters and white spaces between the word and the cursor :facepalm:

I tried every other "Delete ... Backward" available - no luck.

Answer (score 0):

All key bindings can be edited in Xcode -> Preferences -> Key Bindings.

By default the combination you're interested in is assigned to something like Delete Subword Forward. Just remove the combination from the action that you don't need and add it to the action called Delete Forward (or whatever action you're looking for, it's not very clear).

To add a key binding you double click on existing Key value, click +, press Option+Backspace, click somewhere outside the field to save new value.

Comment: Hi man, hope you are well : ) , I use xCode like tan years man, I don't need to know how to use Delete subward backward. I want to delete whitespace backward. Maybe I have to write question differently ? I know there is way to do it there are some plugins or something but need someone to guide me there I forgot how it was.

Comment: If you read my answer carefully, you'll probably notice that what I'm trying to explain is that the combination of Option+Backspace is reserved for Delete Subword Forward (or whatever). You need to remove the combination from there and assign it to the action called Delete Forward (or any other you're looking for).